How can I write a sh if statement that invokes git in a makefile?
I have the following in a Makefile and everytime I try to run the install target, make returns an error number 2.
Here's the code:
.ONESHELL:
install:                                                                                                              
  mkdir -p ${ADDON_PREFIX}/${REPOSITORY_PATH}                                                                         
  repositoryPath=${ADDON_PREFIX}/${REPOSITORY_PATH}/${REPOSITORY_NAME}                                                
                                                                                                                      
  @if [ ! -d $${repositoryPath} ]; then \                                                                            
    git clone --depth=1 \                                                                                             
      https://${REPOSITORY_PATH}/${REPOSITORY_NAME} $${repositoryPath} \                                              
  else \                                                                                                              
    cd $${repositoryPath} && git pull origin main \                                                                   
  fi                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                      
  ln -sf $${repositoryPath}/${BINARY_NAME} \                                                                  
    ${ADDON_PREFIX}/bin/${REPOSITORY_NAME}                                                                            
.PHONY: install

Here's the error:
/bin/sh: -c: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [mfd/antidote.mak:38: install] Error 2

What am I missing?

Keep in mind that the line continuations '' removes the line breaks; i.e., the shell does not see them. Therefore, you must insert ';' at tactical points so that the shell knows that a command ends. You need them before else and before fi.

Yes.  Since you are using .ONESHELL you don't need the backslashes because newlines will be preserved.  But if you do want to use backslashes, you have to add in separators where needed just like you would if you wrote this in a shell script.  If you cut and paste the output that make prints out into a shell script you'll get the same error.

I removed the zsh tag, since there is nothing about zsh in your question.

It's good to accept j6t's answer but just for information, since you're using .ONESHELL you could also write this and it will work:
.ONESHELL:
install:
        mkdir -p ${ADDON_PREFIX}/${REPOSITORY_PATH}
        repositoryPath=${ADDON_PREFIX}/${REPOSITORY_PATH}/${REPOSITORY_NAME}

        if [ ! -d $${repositoryPath} ]; then
            git clone --depth=1 \
                https://${REPOSITORY_PATH}/${REPOSITORY_NAME} $${repositoryPath}
        else
            git -C $${repositoryPath} pull origin main
        fi

        ln -sf $${repositoryPath}/${BINARY_NAME} \
            ${ADDON_PREFIX}/bin/${REPOSITORY_NAME}

.PHONY: install


You can only accept one answer unfortunately.  j6t's answer was perfectly reasonable as well.  I just wanted to show an alternative since you were using .ONESHELL.

The \ at the ends of lines hides the line break from the shell. Therefore, the end-of-line characters in the Makefile cannot act as command terminators in the shell. ; must be used at appropriate places. Essentially, what is written on multiple lines in the Makefile becomes a single-line shell script.
Furthermore, after line continuations have been taken care of, each line is invoked in its own shell. This means in particular, that shell variables do not survive from one line to the next. These assignments must be integrated in the single-line script that needs them.
This makes it necessary to move the @ character to the new beginning of the script, as well.
Finally, when you change the working directory with cd, you must make sure that the change is undone. In this case, it is the simplest to run the command in a sub-shell to confine the "damage".
Below I mark up the lines that are necessary to fix:
.ONESHELL:
install:
  mkdir -p ${ADDON_PREFIX}/${REPOSITORY_PATH}
  @repositoryPath=${ADDON_PREFIX}/${REPOSITORY_PATH}/${REPOSITORY_NAME}; \  # here 
  \  # here
  if [ ! -d $${repositoryPath} ]; then \  # here
    git clone --depth=1 \
      https://${REPOSITORY_PATH}/${REPOSITORY_NAME} $${repositoryPath}; \  # here
  else \
    (cd $${repositoryPath} && git pull origin main); \  # here
  fi; \  # here
  \  # here
  ln -sf $${repositoryPath}/${BINARY_NAME} \
    ${ADDON_PREFIX}/bin/${REPOSITORY_NAME}
.PHONY: install

The mkdir command can operate in its own shell, but could be integrated in the shell script for consistency and only to avoid a "huh?"-moment in half a year's time.

Just to be clear, the OP is using .ONESHELL.  This means many of the extra backslashes you provide are not necessary.  Also I personally recommend using git -C $${repositoryPath} pull origin main rather than using cd.

@j6t, I accepted your answer as a solution.

@MadScientist, I followed your git recommendation.
